# Ubuntu 16.04 FTDI Usb To Serial does not show /dev/ttyUSB*

Tags: 16.04, serial-port

I am connecting a USB to Serial FTDI converter to Laptop running native Ubuntu 16.04,I don't see the /dev/ttyUSB* entry. If I connect the same to Oracle Virtual Box running Ubuntu 14.04 on Windows host, it shows /dev/ttyUSB*, please help what could be the issue with native Ubuntu 16.04

**uname -a**

```
Linux Precision-M4800 4.15.0-33-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 17:21:05 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**lsb_release -a**

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

**dmesg | tail output:**

*

```
[4168693.886387] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6010
[4168693.886389] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[4168693.886391] usb 3-2: Product: Dual RS232-HS
[4168693.886392] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[4169130.482430] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 35
[4169134.326181] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
[4169134.474575] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6010
[4169134.474577] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[4169134.474603] usb 3-2: Product: Dual RS232-HS
[4169134.474605] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: FTDI*
```

**journalctl --follow output when USB is connected:**

```
kernel: usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6010
kernel: usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
kernel: usb 3-2: Product: Dual RS232-HS
kernel: usb 3-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
mtp-probe[25796]: checking bus 3, device 36: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2"
mtp-probe[25796]: bus: 3, device: 36 was not an MTP device

**lsmod | grep usb output:**
usb_storage            69632  1 uas
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             557056  31 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
```

**tree  /sys/bus/usb/drivers/**

```
├── btusb
│   ├── 2-1.5:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0
│   ├── 2-1.5:1.1 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.1
│   ├── bind
│   ├── module -> ../../../../module/btusb
│   ├── new_id
│   ├── remove_id
│   ├── uevent
│   └── unbind
├── hub
│   ├── 1-0:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-0:1.0
│   ├── 1-1:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
│   ├── 2-0:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-0:1.0
│   ├── 2-1:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0
│   ├── 3-0:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-0:1.0
│   ├── 4-0:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-0:1.0
│   ├── bind
│   ├── module -> ../../../../module/usbcore
│   ├── new_id
│   ├── remove_id
│   ├── uevent
│   └── unbind
├── uas
│   ├── bind
│   ├── module -> ../../../../module/uas
│   ├── new_id
│   ├── remove_id
│   ├── uevent
│   └── unbind
├── usb
│   ├── 1-1 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1
│   ├── 1-1.5 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5
│   ├── 2-1 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1
│   ├── 2-1.5 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5
│   ├── 2-1.8 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.8
│   ├── 3-2 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2
│   ├── bind
│   ├── uevent
│   ├── unbind
│   ├── usb1 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1
│   ├── usb2 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2
│   ├── usb3 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3
│   └── usb4 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4
├── usbfs
│   ├── bind
│   ├── module -> ../../../../module/usbcore
│   ├── new_id
│   ├── remove_id
│   ├── uevent
│   └── unbind
├── usb-storage
│   ├── bind
│   ├── module -> ../../../../module/usb_storage
│   ├── new_id
│   ├── remove_id
│   ├── uevent
│   └── unbind
└── uvcvideo
    ├── 1-1.5:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0
    ├── 1-1.5:1.1 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.1
    ├── bind
    ├── module -> ../../../../module/uvcvideo
    ├── new_id
    ├── remove_id
    ├── uevent
    └── unbind

33 directories, 33 files
```

Comment: Did you install drivers for your (I assume) RS232-HS? Check [here](https://blog.mypapit.net/2008/05/how-to-use-usb-serial-port-converter-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: driver modules(*.ko) were missing, upgraded the ubuntu, it started working now

Answer (score 0):

driver modules(*.ko) were missing, upgraded the ubuntu, it started working now