# Ubuntu20.04 ttyUSB doesn't show up when FTDI device connected

Tags: 20.04, usb

My PC can not recognize FTDI device when USB is connected.
I tried to installed FTDI 2.0 driver.

https://ftdichip.com/drivers/d2xx-drivers/

And also did some search, but neither does help.

[Ubuntu 16.04 FTDI Usb To Serial does not show /dev/ttyUSB*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083016/ubuntu-16-04-ftdi-usb-to-serial-does-not-show-dev-ttyusb)

I can find the FTDI device info with `lsusb` command

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0328 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0-CRW
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 2-Port USB 3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 2-Port USB 2.1 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And also `dmesg` shows `FTDI` related info, but no `tty` related.

```
[22912.978093] usb 1-6.1: new full-speed USB device number 29 using xhci_hcd
[22913.204251] usb 1-6.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[22913.204255] usb 1-6.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[22913.204257] usb 1-6.1: Product: FT232R USB UART
[22913.204259] usb 1-6.1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[22913.204261] usb 1-6.1: SerialNumber: AB0LYE9B
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had same issue, fixed with:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-`uname -r`
sudo modprobe ftdi_sio
```

Comment: What in the question tells you that the OP never installed the extra?

Answer (score 0):

It definitely appears that the kernel module for the driver is not installed.  When I plug in an FTDI cable on my Debian 10 system, `dmesg` shows:

```
[1617898.963562] usb 4-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using uhci_hcd
[1617899.184579] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[1617899.185006] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[1617899.185469] usb 4-2: Product: TTL232R-3V3
[1617899.186221] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[1617899.186966] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: FT99IB1Q
[1617899.194639] ftdi_sio 4-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[1617899.195105] usb 4-2: Detected FT232RL
[1617899.197641] usb 4-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Note the last three lines, which don't appear in your output.  These lines are the `ftdi_sio` driver loading.  On my (Debian) system, this driver is located in `/lib/modules/.../kernel/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.ko` and it belongs to the `linux-image` package.

According to an [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=ftdi_sio.ko&mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&arch=any), this module is either  a part of the `linux-modules` or `linux-modules-extra` package, depending on which platform or kernel you have installed.

So make sure you have that package installed and let us know if it works.